# Cassandra on Linode: Dark magic isn't working

Tags: linode, cassandra, private-ip

Yes, I realize I'm crossing the streams by running Cassandra on Linode. Yes, I know it would be better to run it on Rackspace or Amazon, but that's immaterial right now.

Basically, I've got a Private IP set up for each Linode that I plan to include in my cluster. I can ping my Linodes on these Private IPs, so they are able to talk to one another.

Here's some snippets from my "master" Linode's `storage-conf.xml` file:

```
<Seeds>
    <Seed>192.168.133.219</Seed>
</Seeds>
<ListenAddress>192.168.133.219</ListenAddress>
<StoragePort>7000</StoragePort>
<ThriftAddress>192.168.133.219</ThriftAddress>
<ThriftPort>9160</ThriftPort>
```

The server's private IP is `192.168.133.219`.

The problem that I'm having is this: when I go to start up Cassandra, this is what happens:

```
$ cassandra -f
Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.net.MalformedURLException: Local host name unknown: java.net.UnknownHostException: (none): (none)
```

I don't know if it'll help, but here's my `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0 eth0:0

iface eth0 inet static
 address 97.107.137.96
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 gateway 97.107.137.1

iface eth0:0 inet static
 address 192.168.133.219
 netmask 255.255.128.0
```

The Linode has no other configuration. I haven't even changed the hosts file. Let me know if I'm missing something. Any insight is appreciated!

Comment: Sorry it seems I missed something here. What's wrong with running cassandra on Linode and why is it better to run it on Rackspace? Thanks!

Comment: jpartogi: Linode isn't as efficient at writing to the disk. Amazon's EBS is much faster, as is Rackspace's solution.

Comment: Update here in case anybody from after 2011 shows up: this is not the case anymore. Linode runs on SSD as of mid-2014 and Amazon's EBS is not recommended by Datastax because EBS has to contend with network and is unpredictable (read more here: http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/planning/architecturePlanningEC2_c.html). Ephemeral SSD is the recommended approach now on AWS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, guys, I seem to have figured it out on my own. Pretty dumb problem, actually.

```
$ hostname <linode hostname goes here>
$ echo /etc/hostname < "<linode hostname goes here>"
$ reboot
```

And that was it. Holy crap.